# TCP sending images client and server

Tags: c#, image, networking, tcp, client

I have a client application and a server application.
The client application activates this function every 40 milliseconds:
*Note that nstream is a NetworkStream instance.

```
private void SendScreen(NetworkStream nstream)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(nstream);
        ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
        System.Drawing.Image img = sc.CaptureScreen();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(buffer.Length);
        writer.WriteLine(buffer.Length);
        writer.Flush();
        nstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
```

and this is the server application code for receiving the image:

```
private async void ShowImage()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string num = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(num);
            int ctBytes = int.Parse(num);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[ctBytes];
            await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img);
            this.Height = bmp.Height;
            this.Width = bmp.Width;
            this.BackgroundImage = bmp;
        }
    }
```

I can't think of any parts that disturbs these actions.
In the first iteration of the server application, everything works (although I see black screen instead of the screenshot - but the number of bytes sent and received- matches.)
At the second iteration when I writeline num, it shows jibberish and then stops (because it cannot be parsed to int).

Comment: The use of `reader.ReadLineAsync` seems odd, as that will interpret your data as a line of characters, which clearly isn't what is being sent.

Comment: I'm sending first the buffer.Length which is an int (converting to line of characters)..

Comment: Send it as an `int` then, *not* as a string of characters.

Comment: what difference does it make?

Comment: Though I don't think it is the actual source of your problem. It is a possible source of other problems you don't want interfering. Especially if you want to synchronize the transmission of the following bitmap, which really seems to be the issue here.

Comment: well I changed it to read a int but now it's just reading a wrong int in the second iteration...

Comment: someone can even guess?

Comment: i stopped using the StreamReader/Writer... didn't make a difference. The problem is I really can't see anything that causes it.

Comment: is someone able to contact me?

Comment: I have successfully reproduced your problem. My setup sends a Header before each image and expects an ACK. But as with your approach I am only able to receive the first image (incomplete) Right now i'm puzzled as to why this is... I'm gonna wireshark a session and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially I suspect you have a *sync* problem as I had, when I attempted to reproduce your problem (successfully).

Be it a `Header` or a single `Integer` that *announces* an upcomming `Bitmap` transmission. It's all terribly easy to get **out of sync**.

Unless you want to dive into network synchronization and flow control I recommend to use a single `TransmissionObject` for **every** transmission between the server and the client (and maybe another vice versa)

That Object has the **potential** to store any *data* that has to be transmitted. (via inheritance)

Finally when putting the Object on the network stream you may use any *consistent* `Serializer`

The `Serializer` does all the work of syncing up the information to where it is needed (Meta information like length and finally the content aswell)

---

Well in my repro project I came up with [**this**](http://pastebin.com/804XHBfd) Class to hold the Bitmap.

As an example to how to use it on the Server:

```
    public void Send(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        // prepare Bitmap
        BitmapTransmission bt = new BitmapTransmission(bmp);

        // try transmitting the object
        try
        {
            // lock to exclude other Threads of using the stream
            lock (m_objSendLock)
            {
                bt.Send(m_stream);                    
            }
        } 
        catch (BitmapTransmissionException ex) 
        { // will catch any exception thrown in bt.Send(...)
            Debug.Print("BitmapHeaderException: " + ex.Message);
            ///BitmapTransmissionException provides a Property `CloseConnection`
            /// it will inform you whether the Exception is recoverable
        }
    }
```

Where `m_objSendLock` is an Object to prevend concurrent access on the network stream.
`m_stream` is the NetworkStream connected to the *Client*.
`Echo` is a logging mechanism.

The client may receive such transmissions via

```
  public void Receive() {
         BitmapTransmission bt = bt.Receive(m_stream);
         // check for exceptions maybe?

         pictureBox1.Image = bt.Bitmap;
  }
```

Where as again `m_stream` it the NetworkStream connected to the *Server*.

If you want to have a look at the (messy but working) repro project do tell so.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use the BinaryFormatter only (without the BitmapTransmission object as I don't really need it- Why do I need to box the bitmap in another object?) and it throws the following exception: Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization.

Comment: Parhaps I didn't stress that aspect enough, but the reason you want to box the Bitmap in the same object is to synchronize it's transmission with the meta information!

Comment: I tried your class and it throws a SerializationException on receive

Comment: Do you send anything besides the object on the network stream? Checkout the context in which I use it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8D8JKbqVGLhQUs3YnRWYU9FWDg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: well yes, I did, but I stop sending other things when I send the object.

Comment: Yes but did the client receive *everything* you send beforehand? It may be a single ENDLINE that is not read properly or a terminator that is messing up the serializer (or your Bitmap before) That is the reason why I recommended a *single* TransmissionObject.

Comment: I sent a single string and it had reached the client.

Comment: Well that shouldn't be a problem. I cannot really identify the problem this way. I will need to see more relevant parts of your code.

Comment: I really don't know what to do... can you give me your full project or maybe take a look at mine?

Comment: Ok you can download it here: [gdrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8D8JKbqVGLhQUs3YnRWYU9FWDg/edit?usp=sharing) ... as I said it contains a little more stuff than absolutly needed (due to the repro aproach i ve been taking)

Comment: I don't know what's wrong in my project. Are you willing to take a look?

Comment: Well if it's not too messed up, maybe I can see something you missed.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_48n86Kj7BYWUhsU3Q3V1JyQnc&usp=sharing I really hope this link is good, thanks a lot

Comment: Ok you can't just construct a class where the constructor does not terminate and expect it to do anything but construction.... By calling `ShowImage(...)` in the .ctor of your `Screen.cs` you did just that (as `ShowImage` contains a `while(true)` loop) You have some other slight *design flaws*  but I don't want to enter a discussion of good programming practice right now. I added comments at those places. Also note that I implemented some logging as it helps with the debugging a lot. Here you go: [gdrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8D8JKbqVGLhZWlhSjBseS14eG8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize it can cause it, and I still don't really understand why (I always thought the object is constructed, and than the constructor is being called...)